# List Custom button issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, list-view, list-button

I am using List button in Listview as content source of OnClickJavascript, here am using three custom buttons one button is working perferctly. But another two buttons are not working in Chrome, these three buttons are working fine in Firefox. This is my script:

```
"{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js')} 

var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Sample__c)}; 
var prodRecorIds= ""; 

if (records[0] == null) { 
alert("You have not selected any record."); 
} else { 
for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 
prodRecorIds += records[i]+","; 
} 
sforce.apex.execute("Controller","method",{prodids:"{"+prodRecorIds+"}"}); 
window.location.reload(); 
}"
```

Here i need to add any browser supporting script? Is there any solutions to resolve this?

Thanks
Venkatsforce

Comment: What doe the JavaScript console in Chrome say? It should throw an error.

Comment: No it doesn't throw the error..when i click the button no action occurs..

Comment: Does your button text have the double quotes at the beginning and the end? That shouldn't be there.

Comment: No it doesn't, one button is working perfect but other buttons are not working same script am using in this section..

Comment: There's got to be some error in the console then. Do you know how to open the console in Chrome?

Comment: yes i am getting this error in console "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?_=1418443973301&callback=jsonp28'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: So change the http to https in the require script function.

Comment: Thanks for your support @DanielHoechst.. It's working..I deleted that particular URl(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?_=1418443973301&callback=jsonp28%27) in the script then all three buttons are working perfectly.. If use https also in the script the button is not work.. Finally i delete the URl and everything is working....

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is blocking the insecure request to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js. Either change it to https or remove that line since you aren't using jQuery in your code anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code where you are populating the JS records object using a server side function. You generally enclose all server side functions or variables in single quotes while trying to access them in Javascript. The updated code should be.

var records = '{!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Sample__c)}';